# How are a user's tags formulated?

Tags: support, tagging

This is more a curiosity than a pressing question (even though I tagged it as "bug").  But I noticed that my account "tags" seem to change over time.  I figured some algorithm looked at my questions and answers and somehow decided to tag what it thought my specialties to be, accordingly.  Then, today, I noticed my tags as "greek", "fonts" and "siunitx".

Now I can understand "greek" as a tag, since an old answer of mine recently received some attention concerning upright greek symbols.  Fonts?  OK, I'll buy that one too, though it is a bit of a stretch.  But "siunitx"???!  I am embarassed to admit it, but I've never even voluntarily loaded the package (except if the OP's preamble does).  Five hours ago, I left a comment on [Getting ! instead of comparison sign < in cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237083/getting-instead-of-comparison-sign-in-cases) that mentioned the word "siunitx".  The comment got 3 upvotes.

Is that apparently enough to tag me as... what?  Proficient in "siunitx"?  If that is all it takes to tag a user, I had misplaced faith in the tagging algorithm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, the tags represented on the [Users page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users) is dependent on the current time filter. So, you might see a different set of tags under each user depending on whether you filter by [week](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week), [month](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month), [quarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter), [year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year) or [overall](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all).

Now, let's focus on the tags displayed under your user when filtering by week:

[image]

You've earned 120 reputation this week. Nice.

Your tags are [greek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek), [fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts) and [siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/siunitx). These correspond to the *highest-voted*, *active* posts *you* are involved in *this week*. To obtain a list of posts that match some of these criteria, we can use the following [ninja search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/searching): [`lastactive:7d.. [greek]` and then sort by votes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=lastactive%3a7d..%20%5bgreek%5d). Here are the top four results:

[image]

Knowing one of your tags is listed as [greek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek), I've included that in the search query, since there's no other easy way to identify these posts. The [top result](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145926/5764) possesses the tags [fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts), [siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/siunitx) and [greek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) (sorted in order of popularity), matching those in your user flair (sorted in order of popularity associated with you). [Since you're not that active under {siunitx}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A25858+%5Bsiunitx%5D), it's listed last.

Comment: Fascinating!  Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: **the tags represented on the Users page is dependent on the current time filter.**  This is one of the key take-aways from your answer.  Thanks again.